# Scroll within Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a Modal on my site with content inside it. However, I've noticed on Mobile phones I can't scroll inside the content. It seems 'fixed' with no scrollbar.

My **JSFiddle** is here: http://jsfiddle.net/g1kbvn0s/embedded/result/ from here you can see my CSS and Javascript. I've also attached my CSS below:

```
        /* line 863, ../sass/_layout.scss */
        html.cinema-viewer {
          overflow: hidden !important;
        }

        /* line 871, ../sass/_layout.scss */
        #cinema-overlay {
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          z-index: 99999 !important;
          overflow: hidden;
          -webkit-user-select: none;
          -moz-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
        }
```

Many thanks for any assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
#cinema-overlay {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   position:absolute;
}
```

And remove

```
overflow:hidden
```

From the same element.

http://jsfiddle.net/g1kbvn0s/3/

Comment: I have tried this, but unfortunately it still doesn't work on mobile phone.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Can you try it on your mobile?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the fiddle but didn't post the code here, you also need to change position:fixed to position:absolute on the cinema-overlay element, it's quite tricky to test the fiddle on my iphone. I think it is working, but it looks like there is a click function inside the overlay also?

Comment: Afraid it still doesn't seem to want to work for me on my iPhone :-(

Comment: I would suggest stripping down the jsfiddle to the absolute bare minimum of code needed to test this issue. You have so much other code, and js functions, that something else could be causing a different behaviour on a smart phone. I might try in my own fiddle also.

Comment: Excellent idea - will do :-)